# Disable Login Password Screen

Tags: windows-10

My machine did a windows 10 patch upgrade last week and now my machine is prompting me to login with a password every time I start up my computer. Prior to the upgrade I did not have to log into Windows with my password. Any ideas on how to disable this?

I have tried the following instructions from different articles without any success:

Adding a new regedit key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Policies/Microsoft/Windows/Personalization:NoLockScreen
https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-lock-screen

Disable username/password from Netplwiz
https://www.pcworld.com/article/3100057/home-tech/how-to-remove-your-login-password-from-windows-10.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the procedure for disabling passwords using NETPLWIZ. A lot of users have reported problems getting this to work, and I have an (untested) idea of why that may be so. I'm going to have to start with some background information, so please be patient and I promise I will soon come to a possible solution to your problem.

There are two types of user accounts in Windows 10 besides Standard and Administrator accounts. The types I am referring to are Microsoft and Local accounts. Microsoft user accounts are associated with the user's Microsoft account, and facilitate using other Microsoft functions, such as syncing with other Microsoft devices, and using Microsoft Cloud services like OneDrive and Office 365 Home or Personal.

Local user accounts are limited to the computer on which they are defined. They do not communicate or share information with other Microsoft devices or cloud services.

This is relevant to your problem because Microsoft user accounts *require* passwords, and Local user accounts do not. Your user account is probably a Microsoft account, and that is why the NETPLWIZ configuration change is not working. If you switch to a Local account, you will not be required to define a password for the account, and will not need to enter a password during Windows startup, regardless of NETPLWIZ settings. Of course, you will lose the benefits that a Microsoft account provides, but if you don't have other Windows devices and don't use MS cloud services, the impact should be minor. The procedure for switching from a Microsoft account to a Local account is pretty simple, and is described here: https://www.zdnet.com/article/windows-10-tip-switch-back-to-a-local-account-from-a-microsoft-account/.

As I said, I haven't tested this solution, but I found at least one post from a user who had previously tried the NETPLWIZ solution without success, reporting that this solution worked for him. If you decide to try this, please update your post and let us know your experience.

Comment: You can configure a machine to automatically log into a local account that is linked to a Microsoft Account.  You can have the cake and eat it too.

Comment: Switching to a local account worked beautifully. I just followed the instructions in the article you linked (https://www.zdnet.com/article/windows-10-tip-switch-back-to-a-local-account-from-a-microsoft-account/).